# TextView settings attributed text adds inset

Tags: ios, textview, uitextview, nsattributedstring

I set attributed text to my textView and then VC appears text appears did not from the beginning (it like scrolled to 100 point down).

Why and how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you please explain your issue a little more? What are you doing, what is going wrong? What do you want?

Answer (score 0):

[Edited] Add in viewWillAppear or ViewDidLoad

```
 [textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange(0, 0)];
```

Comment: can you explain why this happens ?

Comment: this bad fix because it works only in ViewDidLoad and the prosess of  scrolling is visible

Comment: Let me check and give you better answer.

Comment: i have take UITextView in Storyboard and written above code in viewDidLoad. But I can't see scroll of text in textview. So my question is that "You want to disable scroll of UITextView?"

Comment: No, then I set attributed text to textView from code then textView stay with not scroll position 0,0. I have inset (scrolled down) to around 100 points.